# Looking for good literature on Markov Chains with explicit calculations

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains

I am currently starting my thesis on Markov Chains and am looking for good books and papers that include explicit calculations. I have taken a small course on Markov Chains so the subject is not completely new to me.

All help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Norris' [Markov Chains](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/) is a good starting point (you can read the first chapter from the author's website). I think this is the best introductory text that I know of.

Assmussen's Applied Probability and Queues is another good book.

Meyn and Tweedie's [Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability (1993 version, current version is significantly updated)](http://probability.ca/MT/) is a nice book, but not so explicit. See also Meyn's [Control for complex networks text](http://www.meyn.ece.ufl.edu/archive/spm_pubs.html) (has a link to his "crash course on markov processes" as well). [Free from author's website]

There is also a bit of material in normal probability books (e.g. Durrett's Probability: Theory & Examples)

Markov chains have an extremely wide range of applications, so there are a lot of books you can look at -- you may want to be a bit more specific on what you want to know about markov chains.

Answer (score 1):

For a first introduction, I would suggest reading the book of S. Resnick "Adventures in stochastic process".

For a clear and concise in-depth study, the book of N. Ethier and G.Kurtz "Markov Processes , characterization and convergence"